# Jsp page return "The superclass "jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found" error

Tags: spring, eclipse, tomcat, java-ee-8

I was working with sample spring project  , and all of the sudden the Jsp pages starts to

complain about absent of **"jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet"**. Im not using any type of Jakarta

feature. My web service is Tomcat 9 and for JSP im using **javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1** and

**javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1**. The project structure is Dynamic Web Project with these

setting :

[image]

and error :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

http.HttpServlet mostly means you do not have a Tomcat for the project.

Right-click on the project > Properties > Project Facets > Runtimes, make sure that you checkmark the Tomcat > Apply.

If that does not work you can

Right-click on the project > Properties > Java Build Path > Add Library > Server Runtime, and select your Apache Tomcat 9

Comment: In the absence of both `javax.servlet.http.Servlet` and `jakarta.servlet.http.Servlet` WTP must return an incorrect error message. This should probably be reported as a bug (the Dynamic Web Module version is a `javax.*` one).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Exactly. Also the fun part is even with this error , project can be run an deployed correctly.....

Comment: @AhadPorkar: JSPs are compiled by Tomcat at runtime, therefore Eclipse's _"error"_ is rather a warning that an error might occur.